# iOS: ASIHTTPRequest upload

Tags: ios, sharepoint, asihttprequest

I upload a file to SharePoint with `ASIHTTPRequest`.
At some reason `ASIHTTPRequest` adds additional data to file size. 
**For example**, I upload a DOC-file with original size `1 105 920 b`, but on a server the size is `1 106 150`. Thus file become corrupted.
When I open corrupted file, at the top is:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mydocfile.doc";
filename="mydocfile.doc"
Content-Type: application/msword
```

How can I force `ASIHTTPRequest` to NOT add additional data to original file?

---

**[EDIT]**
The code that I use to upload is simple:

```
request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];
[request setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];
[request setFile:pathToLocalFile forKey:@"docfile"];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:120];    
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: Provide your Uploadingcode

Comment: It looks like somehow your multipart/form-data got written into the file itself. I assume you are first uploading the file to your server, then download the file again and compare it with the original file? Could it be that it's actually the server's fault? Try add a http proxy (e.g. wireshark or Charles) and see whether the right data goes out.